# Modal component is not showing up in Next.JS

Tags: next.js, modal-dialog, tailwind-css

I'm currently working on an application using Next.JS where a user can navigate to a page that contains a table with say 'Projects'. Above the table I have a button that, when clicked, should show a modal to a user that will allow him to add a new project.

I defined a Modal component but I can't seem to get it working when the user clicks the 'Add' button in my application.

Here is the Modal component code:

```
const Modal = ({ show, onClose }) => {

  const handleCloseClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onClose();
  };

  return ( show ? (
    <div className="modal fade fixed top-0 left-0 hidden w-full h-full outline-none overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto" id="exampleModalCenteredScrollable" tabIndex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenteredScrollable" aria-modal="true" role="dialog">
      <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable relative w-auto pointer-events-none">
        <div className="modal-content border-none shadow-lg relative flex flex-col w-full pointer-events-auto bg-white bg-clip-padding rounded-md outline-none text-current">
          <div className="modal-header flex flex-shrink-0 items-center justify-between p-4 border-b border-gray-200 rounded-t-md">
            <h5 className="text-xl font-medium leading-normal text-gray-800" id="exampleModalCenteredScrollableLabel">
          Modal title
            </h5>
            <button type="button"
              className="btn-close box-content w-4 h-4 p-1 text-black border-none rounded-none opacity-50 focus:shadow-none focus:outline-none focus:opacity-100 hover:text-black hover:opacity-75 hover:no-underline"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-body relative p-4">
            <p>This is some placeholder content to show a vertically centered modal. We&apos;ve added some extra copy here to show how vertically centering the modal works when combined with scrollable modals. We also use some repeated line breaks to quickly extend the height of the content, thereby triggering the scrolling. When content becomes longer than the predefined max-height of modal, content will be cropped and scrollable within the modal.</p>
            <p>Just like that.</p>
          </div>
          <div
            className="modal-footer flex flex-shrink-0 flex-wrap items-center justify-end p-4 border-t border-gray-200 rounded-b-md">
            <button type="button"
              onClick={handleCloseClick}
              className="inline-block px-6 py-2.5 bg-purple-600 text-white font-medium text-xs leading-tight uppercase rounded shadow-md hover:bg-purple-700 hover:shadow-lg focus:bg-purple-700 focus:shadow-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-purple-800 active:shadow-lg transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal">
          Close
            </button>
            <button type="button"
              className="inline-block px-6 py-2.5 bg-blue-600 text-white font-medium text-xs leading-tight uppercase rounded shadow-md hover:bg-blue-700 hover:shadow-lg focus:bg-blue-700 focus:shadow-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-blue-800 active:shadow-lg transition duration-150 ease-in-out ml-1">
          Save changes
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : null
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

Below you can find the code that contains the table and the 'Add' button that should show the Modal.

```
import ProjectCols from '../data/projectcols';
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Modal from './modal';

const Table = () => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  const data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      project: 'Test Project A',
      client: 'Customer A',
      pm: 'John Doe',
      active: true
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      project: 'Test Project B',
      client: 'Customer B',
      pm: 'Jane Doe',
      active: false
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="bg-slate-100 h-screen w-full overflow-y-auto">
      <div className='flex justify-end h-20 w-3/4 m-auto'>
        <div className='flex space-x-2 h-full'>
          <button type='button' onClick={() => setShowModal(true)} className='self-center inline-block px-6 py-2.5 bg-green-500 text-white font-medium text-xs leading-tight uppercase rounded shadow-md hover:bg-green-600 hover:shadow-lg focus:bg-green-600 focus:shadow-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-green-700 active:shadow-lg transition duration-150 ease-in-out'>Add</button>
          <Modal onClose={() => setShowModal(false)} show={showModal}></Modal>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='w-3/4 m-auto'>
        <DataTable 
          columns={ProjectCols} 
          data={data} //This will need to be retrieved from the database
          direction="auto"
          fixedHeaderScrollHeight="300px"
          pagination
          responsive
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

When I click the 'Add' button however, nothing happens. The modal does not get shown. I added a console.log in the Modal component just to check if it got called by the 'Add' button function and it did but I still cannot figure out why the modal doesn't show.

I'm using Tailwind CSS in my project and the table page is part of bigger page that contains a sidebar. You can find that code below:

```
import { useAuth } from '../../../lib/hooks/auth';
import SideBar from '../../../components/sidebar/sidebar';
import Table from '../../../components/table';


const ProjectOverview = () => {

  const { user, loading, error, loggedIn } = useAuth();

  return (
    <div className='flex'>
      {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
      {error && <p>An error occured...</p>}
      {loggedIn && (
        <SideBar user={user} /> //Pass in the user role as a prop to decide which items to show in the sidebar
      )
      }
      <Table />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProjectOverview;
```

Can anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong? Is it CSS related or is there another thing that is blocking the modal of being displayed on screen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! I copied pasted the Modal code from a tutorial and didn't notice that the top  of the modal component had a 'hidden' class property in it... Removed it and now everything works fine!